# How to make input text bigger in bootstrap css framework?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, textbox

I have a bootstrap textbox like this:

```
 <input type="text" class="span9" required name="input_text"/>
```

I want my input box to be of height `300px`. For the width, span9 handles it. I used Inspect element in Chrome and overwrite the css like this:

```
input.span9, textarea.span9, .uneditable-input.span9 {
width: 852px;
height: 300px;
```

The text box looks good with the required height and width. But the problem is I can only type in the small portion in between the large text box. I want user to be able to type in the whole text box and even if textbox is not enough, I want to show the scrolling. How's that possible?

Comment: Shouldn't you use a `<textarea>`?

Comment: Oh yes, How could I miss that? I should use textarea? Can I pass the value of textarea into function using simple form like I do with the input box?

Comment: Yes, you can pass it just the same. I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per my comment, it's a quick fix. Use a `<textarea>` instead of `<input>` and it will function the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it sounds like the issue has to do with CSS font-size and/or line-height properties.

An input[text] element will inherit font-size and line-height properties from its parent or else the user agent settings.

Try this:

```
input.span9, textarea.span9, .uneditable-input.span9 {
width: 852px;
height: 300px;
font-size:92px;
line-height:92px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xvznz/3/

As far as "show the scrolling," that's not possible for a standard input[text]. But the above example shows scrolling as you would expect from a textarea element.

So your solution is to tweak font-size and/or line-height CSS properties.